# Is it proper to use django.contrib.auth.models.User in views.py?

Tags: django

I want to create and delete users in my view for my IPN.

```
django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Or should this all be done in models.py? If so, how would I do that?

Not sure if it's technically wrong or just bad style.

Thanks so much!

Comment: what do you mean by IPN? Do you mean `instant payment notification` paypal??

Answer (score 5):

I think the best practice is to use `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()` instead.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
...

User = get_user_model()
```

This way things won't break if you later decide to include a django app that extends or overrides the builtin authentication model (it also avoids a class of bugs related to dependency loops).

Answer (score 2):

yes it is proper to use it in `views.py`:

you can get user model like `paulo scardine`  said ie:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

**Now to Create User:**

```
User.objects.create_user(username='user2', password='pass')
```

**Now to Remove User:**

> It is recommend that you set `is_active` flag to False instead of deleting accounts; that way, if your applications have any foreign keys to users, the foreign keys won’t break.[doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active)

```
user_rem=User.objects.get(username='user2')
user_rem.is_active=False
user_rem.save()
```